# Double join returns duplicate results

Tags: c#, linq, join, inner-join

Here's my query:

```
categories = (from category in db.Cat
              join map in db.Map on category.id equals map.categoryid
              select new CategoryModel
              {
                  Id = category.category_id,
                  Order = Map.order
               }).ToList();
```

Now I want to add another, join, to list all of the categories that actually have items:

```
categories = (from category in db.Cat
              join map in db.Map on category.id equals map.categoryid
              join items in db.Itm on map.id equals items.category_Id
              select new CategoryModel
              {
                  Id = category.category_id,
                  Order = Map.order
               }).ToList();
```

The first query returns 10 categories. The second query should return 9 because one of the categories doesn't have items in relationship with it. However the second query returns about 100 categories. i understand why it's happening - it's because each of the first join has about 10 items and it gives me 10 categories * 10 items.

However I just want to get the 9 categories. What should I do?

Comment: You're doing the second join on the Map's ID, rather than it's category_id.  Is that intentional?  Otherwise, we don't know enough about your table design to help too much more.

Comment: @YtramX Yes it's on purpose, the db design sucks

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Distinct`

```
categories = (from category in db.Cat
              join map in db.Map on category.id equals map.categoryid
              join items in db.Itm on map.id equals items.category_Id
              select new CategoryModel
              {
                  Id = category.category_id,
                  Order = map.order
               }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is almost always a crutch, and generally is not very performant.

Comment: This assumes `CategoryModel`s implement `IEquatable` interface.

Comment: @YtramX It looks like this is EF so this will be turned into SQL where the use of distinct will likely perform well.  You are probably thinking of it's use with Linq-to-objects.

Comment: @Asad This looks like EF, and this would be turned into a SQL statement and it would filter on the DB and whether `CategoryModel` implements `IEquatable` or not would not matter.